# How to iterate over all entries in a single GridView's column?

Tags: c#, gridview, iteration

Consider the following grid view:

[image]

Its fairly empty at the moment but will be more populated.

`peronID` column will always be in the same place. How can I iterate over the first column, counting all `personID`'s equal to a given amount? Something like this (pseudocode) :

```
foreach element in personID
if element == 25
    count += 1
```

Code that populates the GridView:

```
    private void DisplayTable()
    {
        LibraryEntities1 myDB = new LibraryEntities1();
        var people = myDB.People;
        gridViewPeople.DataSource = people.ToList();
        gridViewPeople.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: why can't you just count the underlying object used to populate the grid?

Comment: What is `personID` a collection of?

Comment: This GridView has been populated from an SQL database. But I don't understand what you mean by collection of?

Comment: can you post the code that populates the grid?

Comment: What's your project setup? Do you want to do it in the code behind? Do you have access to the objects if it's a MVVM setup? Based on your simple requirement, you should iterate on `GridView.Rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you operate on the data, not on the grid, so assuming the List below is what you might have bound to your grid:

Given class `Person`:

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

You can group by and sum just like you might do in SQL:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>{
    new Person{ PersonID = 13,  PersonName = "Foo" },
    new Person{ PersonID = 13,  PersonName = "Foo" },
    new Person{ PersonID = 15,  PersonName = "Foo" }
};

var grp = persons.GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
    .Select(p => new {pid = p.Key, count = p.Count()});

foreach (var element in grp)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"PersonID = {element.pid}, Count of Person = {element.count}");
}
```

Output:

```
PersonID = 13, Count of Person = 2
PersonID = 15, Count of Person = 1
```